# Best way to add a domain name search ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dns

Are there any scripts that make a quick domain name search (whois) and verify the domain availability? Ideally this would be an ajax call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like http://www.domaintools.com/api/docs/ exposes what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do the whois lookup server side (otherwise you need to do all sort of cross domain hacks to get it working from client side).